# Device Management Using Google G Suite

Tags: android, mdm

I am stuck in configuring the Device managemnt part in Android using Google G Suite. Some of the configurations i did and deployed to the devices and they are working fine like password restrictions and camera restrictions.

Can it is possible to Wipe all the preinstalled apps from the device using some configurations in Google G Suite?

Can it is possible to send push notifications to all the devices which are under Moble Management?

How to restrict the app installs from play store?

How to create different groups among the registered devices in Mobile Management?

Thanks in advance for your helps.

Comment: Have you seen these docs: [View and manage mobile devices](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1408863), [Manage your organization's mobile devices](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1734200) and [Manage apps on mobile devices](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6328701)?

Comment: Ya, I have checked and did some configurations, they are also working fine for me. I was going with the personal device profile so while adding a device to Google G Suite it is syncing the work profile with the apps that I was Approved.  But I want to disable the pre installed apps in the device. and the queries that I have asked in my Questions.